# ng-repeat loop through object in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm confused how to loop through this data model.

```
$scope.object = [ {person1: {name: 'jon', height: 100}} , {person2: {name: 'joe', height: 200}}, {person3: {name: 'lisa', height: 150}}]
```

I'm trying ng-repeat like this

```
<tr ng-repeat = "person in object[0]">
    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

This of course will only show 'jon'. How can I get all person(x).name? I could name them all person instead of person1, person2, but my data model for my project wont allow that. What can do?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to achieve this writing a directive? You would first transform the model, then send it to scope

Comment: The data is inconsistent. Could you please post the correct object data?

Comment: @GruffBunny That wouldn't work because 'person in object' would just return '{person1:{..}}', etc since each index in the object array is an object.

Comment: @Raghav What do you mean the data is inconsistent?

Comment: @GuilhermeCardoso No I haven't, could you point me in the right direction to solve that?

Comment: @Garuuk: what you have is not valid JavaScript. Post the real structure.

Comment: `[ {person1: {name: 'jon', height: 100} , {person2: {name: 'joe', height: 200}, {person3: {name: 'lisa', height: 150}]` This is not the way to build JSON. Please provide correct code before posting it.

Comment: is data somthin like this   $scope.object = [ {person1: {name: 'jon', height: 100}} , {person2: {name: 'joe', height: 200}}, {person3: {name: 'lisa', height: 150}}];

Comment: <tr ng-repeat = "person in object">
        <td ng-repeat = "p in person">
        {{p.name}},{{p.height}}
         </td>   
     </tr>

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry I edited and added the curly bracket on each object in the array

Comment: See this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/PIUUosdO5YWIW4482460. As answered by Daniel, structure your data object as either array or as a hash but not both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting aside the missing braces in your object data, you could do something silly like

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in object">
    <td ng-repeat="keys in person">
        {{keys.name}}
    </td>   
</tr>
```

...which would do what you want (the inner ng-repeat will only loop one time, since each "person" only has one key ("person1", "person2"...)   But a better solution is probably to change your data structure to either remove those unnecessary person1, person2, etc identifiers and treat it as an array:

```
$scope.object = [
    {name:'Joe'},
    {name:'Susan'}
];
```

or remove the array brackets and treat it as a hash table:

```
$scope.object = {
    person1: {name:'Bob'}, 
    person2: {name:'Ted'}
};
```

With either of those data structures, your HTML template would be the same:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in object">
    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Right now you're trying to structure it as both an array and a hash, which gives no benefit and just makes accessing the data clumsier.

Comment: You're right about the clumsy. It's kind of out of my control at this point. Ganna try the double ng-repeat way

Comment: You can't change the directive?  All you'd have to do is turn those square brackets into curlies...

Comment: It's on the backend, I could and eventually will. But just for the time being it's nice to know a workaround way to do it. I appreciate your answer @DanielBeck

Answer (score 3):

If your Model going to return data in person1, person2, person3, etc..
Here is answer in directive way.

Below is HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat = "person in object">
      <div make-json> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is my controller and directive

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.object = [{
        person1: {
            name: 'jon',
            height: 100
        }
    }, {
        person2: {
            name: 'joe',
            height: 200
        }
    }, {
        person3: {
            name: 'lisa',
            height: 150
        }
    }];
}

app.directive('makeJson', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            var formattedText = "person";
            formattedText = formattedText + (parseInt(scope.$index) + 1);
            elm.text(scope.person[formattedText.toString()].name);
        }
    };
});
```

Hope this could be useful to you. Thanks.

Comment: Careful with that `elm.text()` -- writing to the DOM directly means you lose the two-way data binding.  (Sometimes you do need to do that sort of thing for performance reasons, if you're sure the underlying data won't change, but it's probably not a great habit to use that pattern by default...)